# Getting a single result from table with multiple comparisons

Tags: sql

Good Morning all;

I have the following table

```
Date       Duration         COT             TD            RID
6/26       30               PT              OT            1
6/26       15               OT              PT            1
6/27       60               PT              OT            1
6/27       60               OT              PT            1
6/28       15               SS              MM            1
6/28       30               SS              MM            1
6/28       15               MM              SS            1
6/28       30               MM              SS            1
```

What I am trying to do is pull a record by joining the table on itself where the following is true:

1. T1.TD = T2.COT
2. T1.COT = T2.TD
3. T1.Duration <> T2.Duration
4. T1.Date = T2.Date
5. T1.RID = T2.RID

T1 and T2 are the same table. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2
    WHERE T1.Date = T2.Date 
    AND T1.COT = T2.TD 
    AND T1.TD = T2.COT
    AND T1.RID = T2.RID 
    AND T1.Duration = T2.Duration)
```

Obviously the above gets me 2 rows, as 2 rows meet that criteria. However, I really only want to get a single row from the table. Is there a way to do this, or perhaps a different way to go about it?

Edit: Added additional rows - none of which should be selected. Even though there are rows that do not match on 6/28, they do match - row 1 and 3, 2 and 4 match for 6/28 so should be restricted from the final dataset. In otherwords, if there are any matching records on a day for the RID, then do not select them.

Comment: As you noted you will indeed get two rows based on your criteria. If you want to get a single row which of the two would you want to get and based on which extra criteria?

Comment: Either row would be fine, as both contain the information I need. So whichever is easier to pull

Comment: Why do you say that none of your new rows should be selected?  The 6/28 rows meet all the criteria you mentioned.  Is there another rule that isn't stated?

Comment: Yeah, I wasnt clear in the post - even though there are rows that do not match on 6/28, they do match - row 1 and 3, 2 and 4 match for 6/28 so should be restricted from the final dataset

Comment: Can you add that to your post and I will update the answer to give you a query that removes it

Comment: Which database are you using?  Can you use MINUS (oracle) or EXCEPT (mssql) commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.  Just use the AS keyword to alias the table into two different names and then use the criteria you put forward in your question as follows.

```
Select * from Table as T1 
Join Table as T2 on T1.TD = T2.COT 
AND T1.COT= T2.TD
AND T1.Duration <> T2.Duration
AND T1.Date = T2.Date
AND T1.RID = T2.RID
WHERE T1.Duration < T2.Duration
```

[Here are the results!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fwkP.png)

**UDPATE**

Based on your new criteria you are looking for this where SO19249978 is your table name.  The sub-query which generate the `Remove` table selects the rows that you do not want and then we `join` them to the results. The rows where the values of the join are null are what we are looking for as if the join matches we need to remove the rows.

```
Select T1.Date, T1.Duration as minDur, T2.Duration as maxDur, T1.COT, T1.TD, T1.RID
from SO19249978 as T1 
Join SO19249978 as T2 on T1.TD = T2.COT 
AND T1.COT= T2.TD
AND T1.Duration <> T2.Duration
AND T1.Date = T2.Date
AND T1.RID = T2.RID
LEFT JOIN (
    Select Date, Duration, RID 
    from SO19249978
    GROUP BY Date, Duration, RID
    Having Count(*) > 1
     ) as Remove ON T1.Duration=Remove.Duration
          AND T1.Date= Remove.Date 
          AND t1.RID = Remove.RID
WHERE Remove.Date is null
```

Comment: I added a couple more rows. But the above will pull both rows will it not, as the durations on row 1 and 2 do not match?

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that.  I fixed it to take advantage of your criteria where duration isn't equal.  You can use a where statement to take one side meaning one row and remove duplication

Comment: The above works great until you add in some more rows. I edited the original to expand the dataset. The rows on 6/28 will be selected in the above query. I didnt specify in the post well enough (my bad), but on 6/28, even though the 4 rows have non matching rows, they do also have matching rows, so should not be selected. (If that makes sense)

Comment: @user2271146 Are you saying that if there is a 6/28 with a duration equal to the duration of another 6/28 then no matter what the rest of the data they shouldn't ever be selected?  That is quite different but doable.

Comment: Yes, that is it. As long as there is a matching record on that day for that RID, then it should not be selected.

Comment: @user2271146, I have updated my answer to reflect your requirements as I understand them.  Check it out and make sure it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set criteria about which row you like in final output. Below are some some examples:

If you need any random row in final output:

```
Select top 1 * from t1 as T1 
Join t1 as T2 on T1.TD = T2.COT 
AND T1.COT= T2.TD
AND T1.Duration <> T2.Duration
AND T1.Date1 = T2.Date1
AND T1.RID = T2.RID
```

If you choose to get row based on duration:

```
Select * from t1 as T1 
Join t1 as T2 on T1.TD = T2.COT 
AND T1.COT= T2.TD 
AND T1.Duration <> T2.Duration 
AND T1.Date1 = T2.Date1
AND T1.RID 2.RID   
AND T1.duration > T2.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. You have to use an arbitrary criteria to filter the doubles
2. You should separate the concept of grouping and joining

Try the following solution:

```
    SELECT 
      T1.TD, T1.COT, T1.DATE, T1.RID, MIN(T1.DURATION), MAX(T1.DURATION)
    FROM
       DEMO T1 JOIN DEMO T2 ON (
         T1.TD = T2.COT AND
         T1.COT = T2.TD AND
         T1.TD < T2.TD -- Arbitrary filtering one of each double
       )
    GROUP BY
       T1.TD, T1.COT, T1.DATE, T1.RID   
    HAVING
       MIN(T1.DURATION) <> MAX(T1.DURATION)
    ;
```

See here for a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/581bf/7).